# How to Print a Path in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, pyautogui

I want to make a script open the CMD and then enter a path:

```
import pyautogui as pag
pag.hotkey('win','r')     
pag.typewrite('cmd')
pag.press('enter')
pag.typewrite('C:\Users\XY\AppData\')
```

that doesn't work. So, I tried this:

```
import pyautogui as pag
pag.hotkey('win','r')
pag.typewrite('cmd')
pag.press('enter')
pag.typewrite('C:\\Users\\huba5_000\\AppData\\')
```

However, this entered `C:?Users?XY?AppData?`

What I want it to enter is `C:\Users\XY\AppData\`. Do you know what I should write instead of '\\' ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't used pag, but in general you can try raw strings.
`print(r"C:\Users\XY\AppData")` works notice the 'r' in front of the string. It denotes the string is to be raw and exactly what you type.

Comment: @MooingRawr note that this does not work if the path terminates in a `'\'` as some rudimentary string escaping does still take place

Comment: @Aaron, true but he could pad a space if it terminates with a `'\'` so like `print(r"C:\Users\XY\AppData\ ")` will return `C:\Users\XY\AppData\ ` with a space character. It's a work around I guess from `\\`

Comment: hmm ... it works with the r in front of the string but it still writes a '?' instead of a '\'

Answer (score 0):

when a string is read in from `input()` or from text boxes in gui's (in general.. idk about pag) the extra slashes are automatically put in. They are not automatically put in for string literals in your code however and must be escaped (hence the double slash). Here is a short console session (python 2.7) showing that functionality:

```python
>>> s = raw_input('enter a path: ') #change raw_input to input() for python 3.x
enter a path: \usr\var
>>> s
'\\usr\\var'
>>> print s
\usr\var
```

notice when I entered the path, I did not escape my backslashes, yet when I call the internal representation of `s` they have been put in for me. when I want the output format, I call print to execute any formatting (escapes) contained within the string